# How to decode unicode python arguments?

Tags: php, python, linux, python-3.x, unicode

Using the following code (in PHP) I send an string to a python program:

```
shell_exec("python3 /var/www/html/app.py \"$text\"");
```

The `$text` variable contains a non-English string. the Problem is, When I print the arguments in Python with `print(sys.argv)` I get a result like this:

```
['/var/www/html/app.py', '\udcd8\udca8\udcd8\udcaa\udcd8\udcb5\udcd8\udcb4\udcda\udca9 \udcd8\udcae\udcd8\udcab\udcd9\udc87\udcd8\udca8 \udcd8\udcaa\udcd8\udcb4\udcd8\udcb5\udcd8\udcab']
```

How do I convert this unicode string to original form of the text in python?

Comment: What output do you expect? Those codepoints are surrogates.

Comment: @Wooble I want to use this text in a function which works with normal strings not unicodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python uses your locale's encoding to decode the bytes that it gets from the command line. Default C locale uses ascii. `$text` it seems is in utf-8. Therefore Python has to use `surrogateescape` error handler to decode these bytes into the text `sys.argv[1]` that produces the lone surrogates such as `'\udcd8'` that you see in the output.

You could use utf-8 locale e.g., `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8` or reencode the arguments manually: `sys.argv[1].encode(locale.getpreferredencoding(True), 'surrogateescape').decode('utf-8')`:

```
>>> s = u'\udcd8\udca8\udcd8\udcaa\udcd8\udcb5\udcd8\udcb4\udcda\udca9 \udcd8\udcae\udcd8\udcab\udcd9\udc87\udcd8\udca8 \udcd8\udcaa\udcd8\udcb4\udcd8\udcb5\udcd8\udcab'
>>> print(s.encode('ascii', 'surrogateescape').decode('utf-8'))
بتصشک خثهب تشصث
```

Comment: I get this error when reencoding the arguments manually:`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)`

Answer (score 2):

```
shell_exec("python3 /var/www/html/app.py \"$text\"");
```

(I hope `$text` is strongly sanitised, escaped, or static! If user input got in here you've got a horrible remote code execution vulnerability!)

```
'\udcd8\udca8\udcd8\udcaa\udcd8\udcb5\udcd8...
```

OK what has happened here is that PHP has passed a UTF-8-encoded string to Python, but Python didn't know that the command line input was UTF-8. (Often when you run Python as a command, it can work that out from your terminal, but there's no terminal when it is PHP running Python in a web server.)

Not knowing what the input was it defaulted to plain ASCII. The high bytes in the input aren't valid in ASCII, but Python 3 has a “surrogateescape” fallback handler for invalid bytes, that is applied to the command line when decoding it to a Unicode string. This generates otherwise-invalid UTF-16 surrogate code units U+DC80–U+DCFF, but at least it allows the original high bytes to be recovered if you want to.

So either:

- set the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable to `UTF-8` before executing Python, so it knows what the right encoding is in the first place, or
- change the Python script to pre-process its input to recover the proper input with `sys.argv[1].encode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape').decode('utf-8')`

Comment: `PYTHONIOENCODING` has no effect on `sys.argv`. You should use *the same* character encoding to encode (don't hardcode `'utf-8'`) as Python uses to decode `sys.argv`.

Comment: @bobince +1 and thanks for your warning! setting PYTHONENCODING to utf-8 didn't work but `LANG=en_US.utf-8` works